# Limit image size to ScrollView, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have an image which is set inside a scroll view, though I have set the frame of the scrollView to fixed height and width as shown below, the image goes beyond the bounds (see below picture).

How can I limit the picture to fit inside the scrollView.

```
imageScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight-50)
imageScrollView.clipsToBounds = true // Has no affect on the image
```

[image]

Comment: set your imageview contentmode

Comment: Use aspect fit in your contentMode

Comment: see this for example https://useyourloaf.com/blog/stretching-redrawing-and-positioning-with-contentmode/

Comment: for e.g newImgThumb.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you are using is coded to match the scaling to the device orientation. So, if the *image* orientation doesn't match the *view* orientation, you end up with the image not quite fitting in your scroll view.

You'll need to edit the `ImageScrollView.swift` source file. Assuming you're using the same version that is currently at the link you provided ( https://github.com/huynguyencong/ImageScrollView ), change the `setMaxMinZoomScalesForCurrentBounds()` function as follows:

```
fileprivate func setMaxMinZoomScalesForCurrentBounds() {
    // calculate min/max zoomscale
    let xScale = bounds.width / imageSize.width    // the scale needed to perfectly fit the image width-wise
    let yScale = bounds.height / imageSize.height   // the scale needed to perfectly fit the image height-wise

    // fill width if the image and phone are both portrait or both landscape; otherwise take smaller scale
    //let imagePortrait = imageSize.height > imageSize.width
    //let phonePortrait = bounds.height >= bounds.width
    //var minScale = (imagePortrait == phonePortrait) ? xScale : min(xScale, yScale)
    //
    // just take the min scale, so the image will completely fit regardless of orientation
    var minScale = min(xScale, yScale)

    let maxScale = maxScaleFromMinScale*minScale

    // don't let minScale exceed maxScale. (If the image is smaller than the screen, we don't want to force it to be zoomed.)
    if minScale > maxScale {
        minScale = maxScale
    }

    maximumZoomScale = maxScale
    minimumZoomScale = minScale * 0.999 // the multiply factor to prevent user cannot scroll page while they use this control in UIPageViewController
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a reference to the UIImageView? If so, then set its content mode to aspect fit. Like this:

```
        theImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

The clipsToBounds you set only covers up any parts of child views that are sticking out of the bounds of the parent view, so that's why it doesn't do anything for you.

OR if you're using Interface Builder, set this option:
[image: Interface Builder, baby!]

---

So, what if you don't have the reference to the UIImageView?...
You could iterate through the subviews of your scroll view, and whenever it finds a UIImageView, you can set the content mode like that. Something like:

```
//This is off the top of my head, so my filtering may not be right...
//This is also a one and done solution if you've got a lot of images in your scroll view
for anImgVw in imageScrollView.subviews.filter({$0.isKind(of: UIImageView.self)})
{
    anImgVw.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
}
```

Otherwise, I'm not sure if it's possible without a reference to the UIImageView.

Comment: I am using this library `https://github.com/huynguyencong/ImageScrollView`, when I try to set `zoomView = UIImageView(image: image)`
 `zoomView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @user44776 - the library you are using is designed to make it easy to zoom / scroll an image that is larger than the view. If that is not what you want, then you shouldn't use that library.

Comment: @DonMag, When the library is loaded it is supposed to show images within the view but this part does not work, when double tapped, it zooms and is pannable (this works perfectly).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the screenHeight rather than the viewHeight

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height

imageScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: screenHeight-50)
```